# ESP32 is not sending data to iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui

iOS app is not able to receive BLE data sent by iOS. Transmission of the data works well from iOS to ESP32 but the reception of data is not happening. I am attaching the code. Please help.

```
 Text(isConnected ? "\(batAngle)°" : "Not Connected")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 42))
                .foregroundColor(isConnected ? (((batAngle < setAngle+degreeOfFreedom)&&(batAngle > setAngle-degreeOfFreedom)) ? .green : .black) : .red)
                .scaleEffect(isConnected ? 1.5 : 0.8)
                .offset(x: isConnected ? 10 : 0)

func value(data: Data) { response = data }
    func sendValue(_ value: Float) {
        if Int(value) != Int(self.value) {
            guard let sendValue = map(Int(value), of: 0...100, to: 0...255) else { return }
            bluetooth.send([UInt8(state.int), UInt8(sendValue)])
        }
        self.value = value
    }
```

I have tried to implement this but it is not able to receive data

Comment: Where is the code that shows the reception of data?

Comment: I am using CoreBluetooth example for SwiftUI:
https://github.com/Kazuya-Ito-B/iOS-SwiftUI-BLE-Project/blob/main/SwiftUI-BLE-Project/ViewModel/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetoothViewModel.swift